# Child div not appearing when parent div appears

Tags: html, css, parent

I have two divs, one inside the other. When I hover over a link, I have it set so the two divs appear. However, the parent div appears & the child div doesn't. When I have the parent set to "display:block;", the child div successfully appears. What is going on?

Thanks,

Jacob Saunders

Comment: Sample code, please. Additionally, a http://jsfiddle.net/ would be useful.

Comment: will you please show us what you try yet

Answer (score 1):

I've ceated [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HE7yT/1/) for you using jquery to show how it works. I hope it will help you.

Here's simple script

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
   $( "#hide" ).click(function() {
     $( "#parent-div" ).hide();
   });
   $( "#show" ).click(function() {
     $( "#parent-div" ).show();
   });
});
```